# Google Docs: sending email with variable content from the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to send emails that contains text and variable values from the spreadsheet.
For that i ran the sendemails-script which works well. But at the example the cell that was declared as "var message" didnt contain variable values but only text. 
Is it possible to add "references to values" to this text?

Something like:

Hello,

last week you bought (value of B3) apples and (value of B4) cherries.

I think in Excel you can split text and formular units in one row, is there something like that in GoogleDocs?

Thanks for your help in Advance, i hope you could understand what i mean :)

Marten

Comment: You can take the [Mail Merge template](http://www.labnol.org/internet/personalized-mail-merge-in-gmail/20981/) and build it from there. The variables can be added by column names like $%Column-Name% and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Amit's suggestion is a good idea although it might be a bit complex if you want to keep the whole thing simple and/or adapt it to your needs... It's never easy to analyse a script that is the result of a lot of work... from someone else.

So I wrote a very simple script that does exactly what you ask, nothing more (and nothing less I hope)

It uses 3 columns and the base message has 3 placeholders but you can of course expand it the way you want.

It will be easy to customize it to your use case. I added many log in the code so you see exactly what is going on.

```
function simpleMerge(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = data.shift();
  for(var n=0 ; n<data.length ; n++){
  var baseMessage = "Hello #0#, \n\nlast week you bought #1# apples and #2# cherries.";
    for(var c=0 ; c<data[n].length ; c++){
      var placeHolder = '#'+c+'#';
      var value = data[n][c];
      Logger.log('replacing '+placeHolder+' with '+value);
      baseMessage = baseMessage.replace(placeHolder,value);
    }
    Logger.log('message '+n+' = '+baseMessage);
    //send message to who you want
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the ultradox or mailchimp add-on or many others that do this with more flexibility.